# Is it possible to establish communication between two services which are running in two different process?

Tags: android-service, android-service-binding

Let's say i have started a service1 from my app APP1. There is another service already running and that was not started from my App1 and say it's service2. Now, is it possible to establish communication between these two services.

Answer (score 0):

What about using Broadcast Receivers? service1 should listens for some broadcast (with your defined action) which is send by service2. Similarly Service2 should listens for the broadcast sent by Service1.